# How to store the last two records in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a method that gets a random banner, but I do not want it to show the same banner twice in a row.

```
def random_banner
  @koder = @side.reklamers.all(:select => :id).collect(&:id)
  @koder.sample gets a random ID
  @reklame = Reklamer.find(@koder.sample)
  render :text => @reklame.kode 
end
```

What is the best solution?

TDGS solution:
When I visit the action, it works well, but I have a blog that makes an ajax call to get the banner code, and there, the same banner appear twice in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the last used banner id in the session somewhere, say `session[:banner_id]`

Then, do the following:

```
@koder = @side.reklamers.pluck(:id).reject{|id| id == session[:banner_id}
@reklame = Reklamer.find(@koder.sample)
session[:banner_id] = @reklame.id
```

Comment: Nice solution just what I was looking for. So below this code I would just have session[:banner_id] = @reklame.id right?

Comment: When I visit the action it works well, but I have a blog that makes a ajax call to get the banner code and there the same banner appear twice in a row..

Comment: Why not make the blog pass an extra get parameter, `:banner_id` to the Ajax Request, so that the controller can now which id to ommit. Instead of having `session[:banner_id]` you would have `params[:banner_id]`

But this is not in the scope of your question, so please edit your initial question.

Comment: Why does the session banner id not work when it is a ajax call?

Comment: I use MySQL as database on my local pc and Heroku uses PostgreSQL.. Do you have a solution for PostgreSQL?

Comment: Could you show the example using cookies instead of sessions? Because I think all sessions are cleared on each ajax call..

Comment: After hours of research I decided to go with a row in the table and it worked. So it must be caused by the session being cleared on each ajax call...

Answer (score 1):

Things like this should be stored in the `session` and not in the database. Modifying the session is near zero cost, whereas modifying the database incurs at least a round-trip to the database engine and back, plus the overhead of creating a query and decoding the result.

Example:

```
loop do
 random_id = @koder.sample

 break if (random_id != session[:last_random_id]))
end

session[:last_random_id] = random_id
```

As [James Mason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473691/james-mason) points out, be sure to have at least two things that can be selected or this loop will run forever. Sometimes, as a failsafe, it's better to have either a loop of fixed length, like `10.times do`, or a method that reliably emits random numbers by doing this internally, as `@koder.sample(session)` could test and update.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the previous ID to random_banner and reject the random ID if it matches. You'll need to make sure you don't get stuck in an infinite loop if there's only one banner to choose from, too.